# Accept All Kind of Datetime in Windows Application

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm Working in Windows Application. I'm Developing Simple Notification System based c#.net with datetime concept. this project working in my system. I need validate datetime as dd/MM/yyyy while validate in client system error occur as string not recognized as a valid datetime. because client system have system formatted : dd MMMM yyyy

Let me know how to accept all kind of datetime format in my project..

Used Code:

```
public bool DateValidation(string stringDateValue)
{
    bool A = false;
    try
    {
         CultureInfo CultureInfoDateCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
         DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDateValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfoDateCulture);
         A = true;
    }
    catch
    {                   
         A = false;
    }
    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a windows client you don't need to use a specific culture. When the application starts the [Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.100).aspx) gets set with a Culture matching the client regional settings. [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.85).aspx) parses a string and returns a boolean to indicate success or failure while also creating a DateTime struct bases on the string. Instead of keeping the stringDateValue (with its undetermined culture) you better adapt your code so you can use that DateTime type.

```
public bool DateValidation(string stringDateValue)
{   
   DateTime dtm; 
   bool success = DateTime.TryParse(stringDateValue, out dtm);
   // you might want to keep the `dtm` value, 
   // either by returning it instead of the bool,
   // our make it an out parameter on your method.
   return success;
}
```

If you really need to be sure all dates in your client application use the same datetime format you could force the application to use a specific culture by setting the CurrentCulture at the start of your app:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

and instruct your users to use the dateformat prescribed in that culture (for french that is `dd/MM/yyyy` for the Shortdate pettern and `dddd d MMMM yyyy` for the long date pettern.